# How to print part of a string in bold in react.js

Tags: string

let's say you have a string
let str='Hello I am *developer* this is a *class* of **physics**'

//output should like that in react js

Hello I am *developer* this is **class** of ***physics***

how to acheive in JS

Comment: You need to output the corresponding HTML con your `render` method, in which you insert the appropriate `<b>` tags.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/2557263/alejandro well I have a string I dont know the position of * string * or _ string _  so how can we use this <b> or <i> tag there ?